# Discord.js Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently I'm working on a discord bot with reaction roles. However I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined.

client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
                                    ^
```

I'm using heroku to host my bot, and can't seem to fix this problem

For the sake of keeping this short, I'm only gonna keep the code of the command that is causing the error.

Here's my main.js code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
const usedCommandRecently = new Set();

const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')

const fs = require('fs');

const prefix = ';';

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

// Types message when online and sets Discord Status
client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as cosmo boi`);
    client.user.setActivity({
        name: "to your commands sir | ;help",  
        type: "LISTENING", 
    });
 });

 // Commands

 client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong');
    } else if (command === 'reactionrole') {
        client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    } 
});

client.login('my token is here');
```

And here is my reactionrole.js code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = '801138223974842420';
        const announcementsRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Announcements Pings");
        const giveawayRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Giveaway Pings");
        const pollRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Poll Pings");
        const ytRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "YT Pings");
        const sponsorshipRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Sponsorship Pings");
 
        const announcementsEmoji = '';
        const giveawayEmoji = '';
        const pollEmoji = '';
        const ytEmoji = '⏯️';
        const sponsorshipEmoji = '';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Choose a role you would like!')
            .setDescription('These roles will be pinged when an announcement/event is announced!\n\n'
                + `${announcementsEmoji} for announcement pings\n`
                + `${giveawayEmoji} for event pings`
                + `${pollEmoji} for poll pings`
                + `${ytEmoji} for YT pings`
                + `${sponsorshipEmoji} for sponsorship pings`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(announcementsEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(giveawayEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(pollEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(ytEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(sponsorshipEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === announcementsEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(announcementsRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === giveawayEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(giveawayRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pollEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(pollRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === ytEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(ytRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === sponsorshipEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(sponsorshipRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === announcementsEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(announcementsRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === giveawayEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(giveawayRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === pollEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(pollRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === ytEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(ytRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === sponsorshipEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(sponsorshipRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

Comment: `client.commands.get('reactionrole')` returns undefined. Have you ever set the commands with `client.commands.set()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have declared `client.commands` without actually setting any commands to it. [This guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/) gives a comprehensive tutorial of the command handler you're trying to use. According to the guide, your code should have something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: We don't really know that. OP mentioned that _"for the sake of keeping this short, I'm only gonna keep the code of the command that is causing the error"_.